# How can you access the RavenDB Management Studio when you have an embedded instance in a WPF application?

Tags: ravendb

I'm writing a simple WPF application that will use embedded RavenDB as it's datastore.  I got everything needed to get RavenDB working via NuGet (including the Xap file for Management Studio), however, it is not clear how to make use of the Xap file in this situation.

Has anyone managed to make use of the Management Studio in the super simple situation of an embedded instance in a WPF application without jumping through hoops, creating a hosting site on your box in which to place the Xap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the discussion here:
http://ravendb.net/docs/server/deployment/embedded

Comment: I was able to get the embedded studio working thanks to the link above.  However, I couldn't get it to let me use a port other than 8080.  At least now I can launch the Raven Management Studio via a short cut key in my WPF app and manage the data at a lower level if needed.  Thanks!

Comment: The following line can be used to launch Raven Management Studio from your desktop app if you are using the ebedded http server mode with embedded ravendb:

    `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://localhost:8080");`

Comment: I followed the example at http://ravendb.net/docs/server/deployment/embedded to the letter, but the connection to http://localhost:8080 kept being refused. I found out through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100172/ravendb-management-studio-not-opening-in-browser that I needed to Initialize my documentstore:
`store.Initialize();`