# RavenDb Management Studio Not Opening in Browser

Tags: ravendb

Store initialisation:

```
private static IDocumentStore CreateDocumentStore()
    {
        var store = (DocumentStore) new EmbeddableDocumentStore
                                        {
                                            ConnectionStringName = "RavenDb",
                                        };

        NonAdminHttp.EnsureCanListenToWhenInNonAdminContext(8080);

        store.Initialize();

        store.Conventions.MaxNumberOfRequestsPerSession = 500;

        return store;
    }
```

Config:

```
</configSections>
<appSettings>
    <add key="Raven/Port" value="8080"/>
    <add key="Raven/DataDir" value="~\@App_Data"/>
    <add key="Raven/AnonymousAccess" value="Get" />
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="RavenDb" connectionString="DataDir=~\@App_Data\Raven" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The application works and raven persists some of the data, I just can't get to the management studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the studio isn't served. You have to enable RavenDB's embedded web server when constructing the store instance:

```cs
var store = (DocumentStore) new EmbeddableDocumentStore
    {
        ConnectionStringName = "RavenDb",
        UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true
    };
```